# On-Timer handler fails to run in the interconnected Microsoft Access database

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently managing two databases, let's refer to them as A and B respectively. Database A incorporates linked tables from database B. I've been working on implementing an Auto Shutdown function for database B to close it for the night. I utilized the On Timer Event handler and implemented code that works seamlessly, successfully closing database B. However, I noticed a challenge. Since database A utilizes tables from database B, the auto-shutdown function in database B never executes, as it's technically not the database being opened.

While a straightforward solution would be to integrate the shutdown function into database A, I want to know if there are any work arounds I can do for this issue.

Comment: No. Duplicate the shutdown code into A.

Comment: I figured as much, thanks for the confirmation.